# Typo in introductory statistics book

Tags: statistics

Mistake in book. This is an example from an indtroduction to the central limit theorem written by a professor at my university. Is this a typo?

[image]

Comment: The first sentence in the exercise is grammatically incomplete (the adjective "independent" isn't referred to any noun), therefore yes, something is missing.

Comment: @Gae.S. Shouldn't the math be $P\{T_{144}<150\}=P\{\frac{T_{144}-144}{12}<\frac{150-144}{12}\}=P\{Z_{144}<.5\}\approx .69$?

Comment: @ernesto Yes, your computation is correct. The book seems to have made several typos.

Comment: This question is extremely vague about what the "typo" is referring to.  In fact one might reasonably assume that the typo is referring to the handwritten correction, but your comment suggests otherwise.  @ernesto Please edit the question to clarify.

Comment: @ernesto If the text doesn't describe the distribution of $T_{144}$, then addressing the computations is pointless: if I evaluate them according to the correction you suggested, then I can't know whose mistake it is.

Answer (score 4):

You hit the jackpot on this one: **Three** errors
instead of one.

(a) As @Gae.S. says, and you have suggested in
your handwritten note, there needs to be mention of the exponential distribution with parameter $\lambda=1.$

(b) As you have commented, the z score should be $(150-144)/12,$ not $(144-140)/12$ so the normal *approximation* is $0.6915 \approx 0.69.$

```
pnorm(.5)
[1] 0.6914625
```

(c) In addition, $n = 144$ is not *quite* large
enough for a good normal approximation. The
correct value is $P(T_{144} < 150) = 0.6988 \approx 0.70,$
as computed in R because $T_{144}\sim
\mathsf{Gamma}(\mathrm{shape}=144,\mathrm{rate}=1),$
as can be shown by moment generating functions.

```
pgamma(150, 144, 1)
[1] 0.6987842
```

If the purpose is to show how fast or slowly
the CLT converges, there may be some point to using
a normal approximation. But if one wants the
correct answer to even two places it is
necessary to use the exact distribution theory for $n = 144.$ Because of its marked skewness the exponential distribution "converges slowly to normal'.

A better exercise might be to look at $P(T_{625}< 630) = 0.58,$ to two place
accuracy by either method.

```
pgamma(630, 625, 1)
[1] 0.5842562
pnorm((630-625)/25)
[1] 0.5792597
```

*Note:* Any textbook author has to face the fact that
his or her book *will* contain errors. I am always appreciative when errors are brought to my attention, hoping in vain
for an error-free second (or $n+1$st) edition. I hope you will send the professor a brief 'possible erratum' email about (a) and (b), and perhaps noting the numerical discrepancy in (c).